# How do I bind SqlCommand Parameters when using XML field modify() in C#

Tags: c#, xml, prepared-statement, xquery, sqlcommand

I'm having trouble escaping SQL for use in a XML field with the modify() function:

example code:

```
new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table " +
  "SET xmlField.modify('insert " + xml_string + " as last into (/element)[1]') " +
  "WHERE id = @id", conn, transaction);
```

@id can be bound in C# by SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(..), but xml_string, being inside the modify method, will not allow parameter binding.

So if I want to protect from SQL injection, what do I do with this xml_string? Is there an SQL Escape method similar to System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape() ?

Comment: Are you referring to it properly in the xpath statement? `sql:variable("@id")`

Comment: I tried both simple @xml_string as well as sql:variable(\"@xml_string\") and {sql:variable('@xml_string')}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.k. I finally got it to work:

```
new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table " +
  "SET xmlField.modify('insert sql:variable(\"@xml_string\") as last into (/element)[1]') " +
  "WHERE id = @id", conn, transaction);
```

and then in the parameter binding, be sure to use the XML data type and not Char (!), otherwise it won't work:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml_string", SqlDbType.XML).Value = xml_string;
```

Comment: What happens when you use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml_string", xml_string);`?

Comment: @antisanity: I haven't tried that yet. Could work too I guess, but I like the extra validation.